# Prometheus Table shows missed informations

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

I executed query to get pods running time and I noticed a strange thing that the data in the Graph is not the same in the panel table
as picture shows the table panel display only running pods
[image]

[image]

and when I print the result of this query with java code I only get the data in table

Answer (score 2):

Graph's legend show all metrics that are present on graph. That means, all metrics that were scraped within graphs time range and satisfy your query.

Table, on the other hand, shows only current<sup>1</sup> metrics. Same applies to query executed through code.

Notice: Prometheus' API has two related endpoints: `/api/v1/query` and `/api/v1/query_range`. Those are endpoints to get query results in single time point and over time range, respectively. Documentation on mentioned endpoints can be found [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/).

Your library most likely has similar functionality.

---

<sup>1</sup> Current in relation of time selected for query. In UI, it is configured through field "Evaluation time", in API it's parameter `time`.

Comment: This is my first time using the Prometheus API since yesterday, and I have been trying to figure it out based on what you mentioned. However, I am still unable to identify the specific issue. Could you please provide more clarification? I would appreciate it if you could explain it in more detail.

Comment: @trey, try lowering time range on the graph tab, you'll see lowering number of elements in legend. When time range will reach 1 minute, your legend should match table format.

Comment: yes it does match the graph , I solved the probleme by adding 

**min_over_time**
I apologize for not providing the metrics initially, which would have helped you understand the problem better. Nevertheless, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @trey, Correct, `min_over_time` will result in showing _minimal_ value of every metric that was present over range selector supplied to function. Notice, that there are multiple `<aggregation>_over_time` function. Documentation on them can be found [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time)